# Why does this error occur when I remove these unused variables? Matplotlib animation: self._frames[0].save( > IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, animation, callable

I am animating a 360 rotation of a figure to get a full view of the 3D graph, saving it as a GIF. The problem lies within my function that updates the viewing angle of the figure, which is an input to the Matplotlib class `FuncAnimation`. This is a super simple code, and I'm just trying to understand two lines.

## 1. Working code:

This first block of code works perfectly and generates [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZkCj.gif).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Generate data for the graph
# (replace with your own data)
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3]
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

# Function to update the graph for each frame of the animation
def update_graph(num, ax, x, y, z):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=num)

# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frames=360, fargs=(ax, x, y, z), interval=100)

# Save the animation as a GIF
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

---

## 2. Not working code:

This second block of code is where my confusion begins. It is exactly the same as the first block of code except the `x, y, z` variables are removed from the `update_graph` function and from the `fargs` input to `FuncAnimation`. When running this one, I get the error:

```
> self._frames[0].save(
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Generate data for the graph
# (replace with your own data)
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3]
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

# Function to update the graph for each frame of the animation
def update_graph(num, ax):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=num)

# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frames=360, fargs=(ax), interval=100)

# Save the animation as a GIF
ani.save('animation__.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

---

## 3. Working again

If I go further in deleting seemingly unused bits of code by removing the `fargs` input and leaving `num` (the frame number) as the only input to the `update_graph` function, it works again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Generate data for the graph
# (replace with your own data)
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3]
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

# Function to update the graph for each frame of the animation
def update_graph(num):
    ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=num)

# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frames=360, interval=100)

# Save the animation as a GIF
ani.save('animation__.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

## Question

Why does the code work in cases 1 and 3, but not 2? What does `FuncAnimation` do with the `update_graph` function and the `fargs` input?